# What is the use of **phantom js** over **chrome** when testing using karma?

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have tried both phantomJS and chrome while testing in karma but I am not able to get the advantages of phantomJS over chrome.

Whats the use of phantomJS over chrome.

Why to use phantomJS when we can use chrome

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that you don't need all the time to have the browser when testing, for example when there is a service to be tested - you don't use protractor at all because there are no html elements you need to test, but nevertheless you need to run those tests with Karma. Here comes the usage of phantomejs.
Additionally when running tests, with phantomejs you can do screen capture of the running process - can you do that with chrome?
Check in more details the possiblities of phantomejs and you will see more differences in when/where phantome can be used over chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...... but still I have one doubt...

What do you mean by screen capture of the running process??

Comment: @RohitGoyal check this link http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html for better understanding of screen-capture from phantomejs. Hope it helps.

Comment: what is the need of screen capturing of the running process?

Comment: For example it can be used in companies where tests (not only angular ones, but also selenium tests) run over night, there is a huge amount of tests and in order to have a user friendly test reporting tool, phantome can be used to capture the tests steps while running, then the reporting tool(for example a web app) would display each step and related image - this can be handy for faster error detection in cases when server was down and it is not actually the test that is broken, but it is the environment.

Comment: I would agree with Diana, Phantom is great for running feature level testing when you do not need all the HTML loaded. However, I would argue that once you get into the integration and system level tests running webdriver on a docker container running xvnc would be your best option. You can always run the test and use vnc viewer to watch where it went wrong. I think screenshots just clutter up your system and don't always capture the problem. Also can easily be run overnight. Kinda Funny forever!